# UIBarButton added to navigation not working on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a strange issue in my App.

I initialised a UIBarButton, added the action, custom Image to it and then added it as rightBarButtonItem of navigationController.

The click action is working as expected on **iOS 12.4.1** but fails on **iOS 13.3.1** . My code is shown below.

```
let syncButton = UIBarButton()
syncButton.action = #selector(someMethod) // here someMethod is the method I want to execute on the click
self.navigationItem.rightBarButton = syncButton
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the target to `self`

```
syncButton.target = self
```

OR

```
customBu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and set it as a customView

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue :) though I am curious how it was working on iOS 12

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, Hope its working fine

```
            let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33, height: 33)
        let btnSideMenu = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame)
        btnSideMenu.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        btnSideMenu.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "burger"), for: .normal)
        btnSideMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnSideMenuTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnSideMenu)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftBarButton, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

OR

```
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
let play = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Play", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(playTapped))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, play]
```